# how can I set the focus on inputText when I click reset button on Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

The scenario is like this:

I have a form with an inputText and one button for reset the form. When I push the button, the form must be reset and the focus should point to the input text.

I am using primefaces 5.1. The codes go something like this:

```
<f:form id=myForm>
<h:panelGroup id="divInput" layout="block">
    <p:focus context="divInput"/>
    <p:inputText id="myInput"/>
    <p:commandButton type="reset"/>
</h:panelGroup>
</f:form>
```

I tried first with this oncomplete with no luck:

```
<p:commandButton type="reset" oncomplete="myInput.focus()"/>
```

The second time I tried with this script:

```
<script>
    //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button and set focus
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //attach click event to button
        $("#myForm [type='reset']").click(function(){
            $("#myForm [name='myInput']").focus();
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can write just `$('#myInput').focus()` instead of `$("#myForm [name='myInput']").focus();`

Comment: The target component will regain focus automatically, if you update the enclosing/contextual component - `<h:panelGroup>`, when the given `<p:commandButton>` is clicked (this extra JavaScript/jQuery stuff should not be needed).  Reset on the other hand, could mean differently. In PrimeFaces, you may also want to use `<p:resetInput target="targetComponent"/>` in conjunction with `<p:commandButton>` to clear components which are dirtied by conversion/validation error(s) (which does not mean that values held by those components will be cleared automatically).

Comment: I tested some solutions as you say, but I think this option involves communication with the server because on the real app I have more info on the panelGroup, and I have no luck getting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solved simply adding the event onclick with the right call to the method "focus":

```
<p:commandButton onclick="$('#myForm\\:myInput').focus();" type="reset"/>
```

Valid solution for RequestScoped bean.

Comment: If you reset the value held by that `<p:inputText>` (simply using JavaScript/jQuery tricks on the client-side, or `<p:commandButton type="reset">`), the corresponding value in model (the bean) will not automatically be reset unless you communicate with the server (using `action` or `actionListener`). So, anyway it appears that you need to communicate with the server, if you also want to clear that value in the model. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Tiny, but in my case I'm using a RequestScoped bean.